# PHP get string between strings

Tags: php, string

I want to get the string between //begin and //end of the following php code
I've thought of using a regular expression but I have no idea about how to go about extracting the target string. Any advice would be appriciated.

```
<?php
$test='
//pool test area
//begin

var out0=0;

//end
// end pool test area

';
?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a substring between two strings in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/5696412). A regex would be `#//begin(.+?)//end#s`

Comment: didn't see the dupilcate thanks for the link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression or convert the string to an array and loop through the newly created array, try this:

```
<?php

$test = '
//pool test area
//begin

var out0=0;

//end
// end pool test area

';

function getString($testString, $start, $end) 
{
$arr = explode($start, $testString);   
foreach ($arr as $item) {     
    if (strpos($item, $end) != false){
        $aResult[] = substr($item, 0, strpos($item, $end));        
    }
  }
  return implode("", $aResult);    
}

echo getString($test, "//begin", "//end");
```

Output:

```
var out0=0;
```